# How to connect using IPMI

Tags: mac, ipmi

I want to install an OS on a server using IPMI. How do you know the IP address to connect to using IPMI? I have the server plucked into the wall through an Ethernet cable and it should be assigned an IP address from DHCP. I will be connecting from a Mac.

Comment: And you usually need java installed.  There will be a remote control feature that'll give you the ability to see a screen via a java viewer .  A menu in there normally allows you to attach ISO installation media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the IP assignments on the DHCP server to find out the assigned address.

I usually connect a KVM (Keyboard Video Mouse, often as a switch) as a first step to configure IPMI with a static address.

Comment: KVM = keyboard video mouse?

Comment: I got it working now, but I've never seen a KVM with an Ethernet port before?

Comment: he meant boot the server with the monito/keyboard attached and look in the settings and assign a static ip to it through the bios ;)

Comment: @art3mis: No, not necessarily. KVMs with  KVM over IP, as often offered by IPMI/management subsystems, are also available as standalone products. These days I think it's mostly used by hosters offering very cheap non-VPS root servers where consumer grade hardware is used instead of real server stuff with management capabilities. KVMoIP or not, I use this to configure the onboard management controller if it's not alreay pre-configured by the supplier.